# Reg ex for Date: YYYYMM--

Tags: regex, date

What's the regex for a date with no date value ("--") and no separator?

Format: *YYYYMM--*

201201--

Comment: Do you need to accept years <=999?  Will years in those ranges be zero padded?  E.g. 0999?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  ([12][0-9]{3})(0[1-9]|1[0-2])--
```

… handles dates from 100001-- to 299912--

*Edit* corrected dates per @m42, oops!

Comment: Thanks, yesterday was an holiday in the US, so I'm doing my Monday Morning typos a day late :-]

Comment: I've removed some unnecessary backslashes; you might also want to add a `\b` before the regex to make sure the match starts at a "word boundary" (and not as a submatch of `9876543210012--` or something like it).

Comment: ah, I tend to over-escape these things, as I rarely find a language that gripes about too many backslashes, but frequently have troubles with too few :-) But thanks anyway. And, yes, this doesn't handle anchoring at all.

Answer (score 0):

The code to match it as a year.month.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string txt="201201--";

      string re1="((?:[0]?[1-9]|[1][012])(?:(?:[0-2]?\\d{1})|(?:[3][01]{1}))(?:(?:[1]{1}\\d{1}\\d{1}\\d{1})|(?:[2]{1}\\d{3})))(?![\\d])";
      string re2="(-)";
      string re3="(-)";

      Regex r = new Regex(re1+re2+re3,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Singleline);
      Match m = r.Match(txt);
      if (m.Success)
      {
            String mmddyyyy1=m.Groups[1].ToString();
            String c1=m.Groups[2].ToString();
            String c2=m.Groups[3].ToString();
            Console.Write("("+mmddyyyy1.ToString()+")"+"("+c1.ToString()+")"+"("+c2.ToString()+")"+"\n");
      }
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```